# How to connect to Microsoft SQL server using GORM in golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to connect to a microsoft SQL server using GORM: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm

But I cannot seem to find any tables when I try using db.HasTable() and I checked the credentials which are fine. I did receive a message that GORM doesn't officially support MSSQL and it runs in compatibility mode but I also included an SQL driver: github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb
that's used for MSSQL. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

I found my error, I was importing the wrong MSSQL driver, gorm already has one
import _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post this answer just to expatiate @Eduardo Carstillo answer above.
I had this same issue and i got the error
`mssql is not officially supported, running under compatibility mode.`
The error occur because the Gorm library does not support mssql by default however a it has been implemented in a the `gorm dialects`.

To resolve this issue. just add an import statement for the gorm dialects. see the full mssql connection bellow.

```
import (
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
)

func main() {
  db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://username:password@localhost:1433? 
  database=dbname")
  defer db.Close()
}
```

refer to the gorm doc for more detail. 
http://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html`